# how (during fresh install) to make the boot partition at least twice its normal size

Tags: boot

I've had occasion to run out of space and not been able to update (it was from 21.04 to 21.10) ... I scrambled around, removed snaphots and anything else I could think of and created the needed room on boot.  But during that scramble I googled fairly extensively about making boot partition bigger and found quite a few others who hit the same problem.

I'd like to just circumvent the whole thing by making the boot partition a lot bigger than the install process currently makes it.

However reading up on the process the devs have come up with I see its way more involved than I am equipped to understand or deal with.

I hoped that someone could tell me in plain english how to do this.  Room is not a question in todays disk sizes and prices so is it possible with minimal skill and experience to increase that partition  by at least 100 percent and more if that wouldn't make the task too complicated.

My feeling is, barring making the technical problems quite a lot more complicated, .. why skimp on boot or swap? ... I think I'd like both to be much larger if the technicalities are not unreasonably difficult.

Any comments on this would be quite welcome .. pro or con.

---

> I've had occasion to run out of space and not been able to update (it was from 21.04 to 21.10)

I see buy the answers to OP that I've made a grave mistake there.
I failed to mention that I am choosing (and chose) the zfs option.

Once that choice is made the installer will partition  your install disk for you, so unless you back out of the zfs choice the "something else" choice is no longer an option.

[Image of partitioning scheme installer will use, taken during vbox install (ubuntu-22.04 running on ubuntu-21.10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rK9Sq.png)

(I attempted to copy paste `the text in that image' from the installer window but it doesn't work.)

These are the partitions I was speaking of.  And as you see ... there are no sizes shown so no way to just copy the scheme but make partitions bigger.  At least not during the install.

With this in mind I'd still like to hear some suggestions for making bpool bigger.

Comment: Do you even need a separate /boot partition?  LVM and encryption might make one necessary, but otherwise, a /boot directory in the root is all that's needed, and you avoid the "/boot too small" problems.

Comment: Are you sure your issue is with boot partition? and not the ESP???  (*uEFI system partition*)   I've not had issues with `/boot` in years using the defaults, but do use a larger ESP (EFI system partition; which is /boot/efi/) on boxes where I'm going to do multiple QA-test installs to.   If you want a larger partition; use *something else* (you weren't specific on system so I've assumed desktop & `ubiquity` installer but adjust for whatever you'll use) and create the partition size you want & use it.  I'd recommend not using /boot partition too though; use defaults & allocate enough space to /

Comment: IMHO I would use 100% /root  and create a "swap file" in /root double the size of your RAM memory instead of a separate swapfile partition. That way you can always easily adjust the swapfile size if you upgrade your RAM. If you start to run out of hardisk space, it is easy to move /home or other directories to a newly added drive.

Comment: There is no need to create any other partitions other than /root on a fresh install. Delete any partitions created on install and allocate to /root "`/`"

Comment: *"I see its way more involved"* - I think you are making things way more involved then they need to be.  If you use the guided installation when you install Ubuntu, everything is on one partition. Unless you have a specific need to separate the file system into different partitions, don't.  This is not "skimping" on boot or swap.  A swapfile is the default instead of a swap partition and boot won't run out of room if you don't put an artificial cap on the space it can use, which is what you're doing when you assign it a partition.